# Problems with php code on homepage template

Tags: php, css, templates, video

I'm new here and I am not a developer - I'm learning code on the fly so please be gentle :)

Anyway, I am having trouble with a video section on my client's homepage:
https://aurorapredictions.com

First, there is a bit of "extra" background below the video that I don't know why it's there. It magically goes away when you zoom in or out. Strange.
[Picture Evidence Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StBlS.jpg)

Second, depending on the browser, at 100% zoom-in rate, the top of the logo and bottom of the bottom are cut off.
[Picture Evidence Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXqA7.jpg)

How do I fix these issues? Below is the code for that section. THANKY YOU in advance!

```
<section class="videoHolder">
<div class="header-video" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" data-vide-bg="mp4: wp-content/themes/AuroraCustom/video/Aurora_3MB, ogv: wp-content/themes/AuroraCustom/video/Aurora_3MB, webm: wp-content/themes/AuroraCustom/video/Aurora_3MB, poster: wp-content/themes/AuroraCustom/video/Aurora_3MB" data-vide-options="loop: false, muted: false, position: 100% 100%">
    <div class="tagsholder">
        <div class="shell">
            <div class="tags line1" id="line1">
                <?php echo CFS()->get( 'title_1' ); ?> </div>
            <div class="tags line2">
                <?php echo CFS()->get( 'title_2' ); ?> </div>
            <div class="tags line3">
                <?php echo CFS()->get( 'title_3' ); ?> </div>
            <div class="tags line4">
                <?php echo CFS()->get( 'title_4' ); ?> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line5">
        <div class="large-logo"> <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/aurora_large_logo.png" alt="Aurora Predictions"/>
            <p class="l5tag logo_title">Discover your tomorrow today </p>
            <?php $link1 = CFS()->get( 'button_1_link' ); ?>
            <?php $link2 = CFS()->get( 'button_2_link' ); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $link1[url]; ?>" target="<?php echo $link1[target]; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btnscla">
                <?php echo $link1[text]; ?> </a>
            <!--<a class="btn btn-gray btnscla btn-btm" href="<?php echo $link2[url]; ?>" target="<?php echo $link2[target]; ?>">
                <?php echo $link2[text]; ?> </a>-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the background from (or make it black):

```
.videoHolder {
    background-image: url(../video/Aurora_3MB.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

As you also have it on the wrapping div (with a bunch of other stuff which is generated by your code):

```
<div style="
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: -1; 
  top: 0px; 
  left: 0px; 
  bottom: 0px; 
  right: 0px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  background-size: cover; 
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: 100% 100%; 
  background-image: url(&quot;https://aurorapredictions.com/wp-content/themes/AuroraCustom/video/Aurora_3MB.jpg&quot;);
">
  <video autoplay="" style="margin: auto; position: absolute; z-index: -1; top: 100%; left: 100%; transform: translate(-100%, -100%); visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; width: auto; height: 842px;">
    <source src="wp-content/themes/AuroraCustom/video/Aurora_3MB.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="wp-content/themes/AuroraCustom/video/Aurora_3MB.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="wp-content/themes/AuroraCustom/video/Aurora_3MB.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  </video>
</div>
```

Or remove the `poster: wp-content/themes/AuroraCustom/video/Aurora_3MB` from your above code, having the image as a background to both divs is the issue.

[image]

Comment: Hi Lawrence - Thanks for the quick response! I'm confused with your response. I can't find any of that code in the php homepage theme files (what I copied and pasted earlier). Or, are you saying to add it? I don't know what the code "produces" so you'll have to point me in the direction of what I have in the php file to change.

Comment: I'm looking at the DOM of the page, do the same you can clearly see its adding video/Aurora_3MB.jpg to the div (most likely added via the `poster` attribute in your code).. its also in `.videoHolder` css remove the one from css as said and it should fix the issue (though your have white in its place which is why I said make it black background)

Comment: CSS is in https://secureservercdn.net/198.71.233.9/e6a.c0b.myftpupload.com/wp-content/themes/AuroraCustom/css/style.css line 39816 (eek look for .videoHolder)